# Comma Delimited String of Doubles to Array -- How to keep Precision

Tags: c, json, floating-point, json-c

I am working with the JSON-C Library v0.11 to output JSON. I have a string of doubles in a char * that I need to output as an array.

I have: `const char* doubles = "0.1234, 0.5678, 1.1234, 1.5678";`

I want to output:
`"doubles", [0.1234, 0.5678, 1.1234, 1.5678]`

My issue is that the JSON-C library when using `json_object_new_double` adds trailing zeroes and I want my doubles to be exact.

Is there a workaround to this?

```
char *token = strtok(doubles, ",");
while (token != NULL) {
    double current = atof(token);
    json_object_array_add(my_array, json_object_new_double(current));
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}

// Add the key-value pair as an array
json_object_object_add(root_obj, "my_array", my_array);
```

Comment: Why not call `json_object_new_string(token)` instead of converting `token` to a double?

Comment: because then the array will have the doubles in quotes as strings like this:
"doubles", ["0.1234", "0.5678", "1.1234", "1.5678"]

Comment: The resulting doubles _are_ exact. There does not exist an exact IEEE double representation of 0.5678, since that's in decimal whereas a double is in binary. In binary 0.5678 is a forever-repeating fraction, just like 1/3 is in decimal. The json-c library is correctly representing the double exactly as 0.56779999999999997 converted back to decimal, since that's the closest the IEEE double representation can get to the decimal value 0.5678.

Comment: Let's be clear. You don't have doubles to start with. You have string representations of decimal number with fractional parts. You would like to *convert* those to `double`, and it is there that the precision issues arise.

Comment: In any case, additional trailing zeroes won't change the values.

Comment: @hko `"%1.15g"` will not give trailing zeroes. Anyway, the default is `"%.17g"`, which will not give trailing zeroes either. Trailing zeroes are output only with the `#` flag. So I don't know why @spiderwebdev is getting trailing zeroes.

Comment: I cannot upgrade the version due to limits on the version of CentOS, and thus cannot use json_c_set_serialization_double_format. It does not change the value to add trailing zeroes but adds space when many doubles are given extra zeroes - think tens of millions. Representing them as strings is not an option either.

Answer (score 1):

The **[json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)** library uses `snprintf` with a format `"%.17g"` to convert the `double` values as strings for output.  This produces an accurate conversion such that any 2 different `double` values produce different output and converting back this output produces the original `double` value.  Javascript interpreters use more sophisticated logic to produce minimal strings when converting numbers to strings.  The library should use that too, but it seems the authors are not aware of the issue.  They do however provide a hack to modify the conversion behavior: `json_c_set_serialization_double_format`.

There is no *exact* binary representation of `0.5678` as a `double` in the ubiquitous [IEEE binary 64 bit format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) used in most systems.  The closest `double` value in this format is **5114287736841935 * 2<sup>-53</sup>** whose exact decimal representation is `0.56779999999999997140065488565596751868724822998046875` (and `0x1.22b6ae7d566cfp-1` in hexadecimal floating point format). If you convert this value to decimal with 4 to 16 decimal places, the conversion produces `0.5678`, but the library uses 17 places to ensure that all `double` values produce different output, so on your system, the string produced by the library is `0.56779999999999997`, yet `atof("0.56779999999999997")` and `atof("0.5678")` should produce the same `double` value.

To avoid this problem, you would need to use decimal floats, which json-c does not seem to support or a way to specify the maximum number of decimals in the conversion to string operated by json-c, and the package does provide an API to specify a conversion format: `json_c_set_serialization_double_format` in the current version 0.17, much more recent than your old 0.11 version.

Here are my recommendations:

- you should probably upgrade your version of json-c to a more recent release.
- you could ignore the change in representation of the `double` values as they will convert back to the same `double` value upon reading in the destination system.
- you could use `json_c_set_serialization_double_format` to specify a conversion format that produces the expected output.
- you might consider a simpler package to handle the json format.

Comment: I cannot upgrade the version due to limits on the version of CentOS, and thus cannot use json_c_set_serialization_double_format. It does not change the value to add trailing zeroes but adds space when many doubles are given extra zeroes - think tens of millions. Representing them as strings is not an option either.